# Stop WooCommerce For Reducing Stock On Abandoned Admin New Order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

If an admin goes to create an order but abandons it, the stock level is still reduced.

Steps to reproduce:

1. install WordPress
2. install WooCommerce
3. create simple product and tick "manage stock?" and set stock level to 10
4. view on front-end (see screenshot before.png)
5. as admin create new order but don't save it (new -> order -> add item -> exit page)
6. view on front-end (see screenshot after.png)
7. Notice stock level has been reduced even those order wasn't saved.

Is there anyway to avoid this?

**Before.png:**
[image: before.png]

**After.png**
[image: after.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked on this issue and wrote a basic code for that.

**Hooks used:** "woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons" for Admin Order Add Item(s) and "woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta" for Admin Order Creation/Update.

**First part:** Stop reducing stocks of items that added while the order has not been created.

```
// define the woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons callback 
function action_woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons( $order ) { 
    $orderID = $order->ID;
    //check if this is the admin manual order creation 
    if(get_post_status($orderID) == "auto-draft" && get_post_type($orderID) == "shop_order")
    {
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item )
        {
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
            $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
            $product_quantity = $item->get_quantity();

            if($variation_id == 0)
            {
                $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
                wc_update_product_stock($product, $product_quantity, 'increase');
            }
            else
            {
                $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
                wc_update_product_stock($variation, $product_quantity, 'increase' );
            }

            // The text for the note
            $note = __("Stock incremented due to the auto draft post type. Stock for each item will be decremented when this order created.");
            // Add the note
            $order->add_order_note( $note );
        }
    }
}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons', 'action_woocommerce_order_item_add_action_buttons', 10, 1 );
```

**Second Part:** Reduce stocks of items that added if order is created.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'woocommerce_process_shop_order', 10, 2 );
function woocommerce_process_shop_order ( $post_id, $post ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $post_id );

    //check if this is order create action, not an update action
    if(get_post_status($post_id) == "draft" && get_post_type($post_id) == "shop_order")
    {
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item )
        {
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
            $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();
            $product_quantity = $item->get_quantity();

            if($variation_id == 0)
            {
                $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
                wc_update_product_stock($product, $product_quantity, 'decrease');
            }
            else
            {
                $variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);
                wc_update_product_stock($variation, $product_quantity, 'decrease' );
            }

            // The text for the note
            $note = __("Stock decremented for all items in this order.");
            // Add the note
            $order->add_order_note( $note );
    }
    }
}
```

Tested and works fine. I hope this will help you. Have a good day.